# Opening Vim help in a vertical split window

Tags: vim

Is there a way to get Vim help to open in a vertical split pane rather than a horizontal one?

Answer (score 145, accepted):

[`:vertical` (`vert`)](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#:vertical) works:

```
:vert help
```

You can also control whether the window splits on the left/top or the right/bottom with [`topleft` (`to`)](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#:topleft) and [`botright` (`bo`)](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#:botright). For example, to open help in the right window of a vertical split:

```
:vert bo help
```

Comment: how can i map that so when I run :help ____ it always opens like that?

Comment: @Tallboy Try `cnoremap help vert help`. This creates a command mode mapping so that when you type `help` in command mode you will see it expand to `vert help`.

Comment: @Kazark: `cnoremap help vert help` makes each letter of `help` appear by itself, so the word `help` doesn't appear on the command line.  Is there any way to fix that?  Maybe something other than `cnoremap`?

Comment: To improve more: you can use cabbrev to *redefine*  `h` as `vert h`:  `:cabbrev h vert h`. Then every time you type `:h`, it will automatically expand to `:vert h`.

Comment: @AaronShen: best solution ( in combo with this answer )!

Comment: `:cabbrev h` redefines `h` any time you're in command mode. I just want to redefine how `:help` works, which I've been typing for years. For this, `cabbrev help vert bo help` is perfect. However, typing `:h` will still trigger the default help window behaviour.

Answer (score 54):

As an alternative to Haroogan and Sean's answers you can use the `FileType` event for the autocommand like this:

```
autocmd FileType help wincmd L
```

Although this will change the position of any help window as well as moving the window after manually placing it if the file you are looking at changes. But I believe that this is a problem with any solution.

Comment: Simple, and (if I understand correctly) the side effects are negligible.  Why is this not the accepted answer!?  And why does a completely irrelevant answer (`:vsplit`) have lots of upvotes!?

Comment: I upvoted both this and Haroogan's answers for their simplicity. I’m not very familiar with autocmd events and I was wondering what the reason is for `help,*` instead of simply `help`.  
Also, I noticed that this command works when I add it to my `_vimrc` and start a new instance of GVim but not when I run the command in my current GVim session (I have to manually `:set ft=help` to trigger the autocmd).

Comment: Thanks for the comment: the `*` was not actually needed. As far as I can understand for the current session vs new session, in the new session you would need to re-source your `vimrc` for any changes to take effect, additionally if the file is already open in the buffer and `:help` just takes you to a different part of the file, this `autocmd` will have no effect

Comment: Will there be shorter way to also address :h with the same autocmd? Currently i write it in an extra line: ``autocmd FileType help wincmd L``
``autocmd FileType h wincmd L``

Comment: This autocmd addresses the issue by looking at the filetype of the help files. All help files are of the `help` filetype, thus on the setting of the `help` filetype this autocmd will run. You can test this by doing `:sef help` in any file while there is a split in your window, thus @danbruegge's second autocmd would not be needed

Comment: "Why is this not the accepted answer!? " Because I didn't ask for a way to always open help in a vertical window.

Comment: Actually I think this is the best solution. In my case, I prefer to use `autocmd FileType help wincmd H` because I like to view the help files in the left window.

Comment: To get it to start applying in your current session you can just unload the help buffer with bunload and then it will trigger the autocmd when you use next open it.

Comment: This doesn't seem to persist here. Couldn't put my finger on it, but it would work fot a bit then switch back to a horizontal split. @Alexander Shukaev 's answer seems to work best and is probably best practice.

Comment: In neovim, `autocmd FileType help wincmd L` only happens the first time a help window is opened.  Try opening a help window, closing it, then opening a help window.  After the first help window, the rest are opened in a horizontal split.

Answer (score 31):

No need to remap any commands or introduce weird aliases like `:Help`. Here is the solution. Create `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/help.vim` where you can override any Vim settings particularly for `help` and add the following line there:

```
autocmd BufWinEnter <buffer> wincmd L
```

This hook will ensure that any `help` file is opened in vertical split. Furthermore, it does not have a side effect described in Sean's answer. Personally, this is perfect solution for me so far.

Hope this helps. Best of luck.

Comment: This seems to be the best solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 22):

This command should do it:

```
:vert help
```

Comment: I don't get this. All `:vsplit` does is split the current window vertically. How does this open help in a vertical pane?

Comment: @doubleDown 7 years later... `:vert` is not the same as `:vsplit`. From the docs: _"`:vert {cmd}`, Execute {cmd}.  If it contains a command that splits a window, it will be split vertically."_ EDIT: oh your comment was posted when this answer was incorrect...

Answer (score 8):

To make help files always open in a vertical split on the right, put this in your vimrc:

```
augroup helpfiles
  au!
  au BufRead,BufEnter */doc/* wincmd L
augroup END
```

This will have the side effect of having anything with "doc" in its path open in a vertical split, but that may not be a problem for you.  It isn't for me.  If you would rather it open in a left vertical split, or anything else for that matter, you can change `wincmd L`.  You can learn more about it with `:he wincmd`

Comment: Check the filetype before split, `:au BufEnter */doc/* if &filetype=='help' | wincmd L | endif`

Comment: This is awesome! `autocmd FileType help wincmd L` only works one time for me, this works very well!

Comment: This one works for neovim. `autocmd FileType` doesn't work in neovim if you close and reopen help because help buffer remains hidden. But BufEnter with `if &filetype=='help'` does the trick. Also after `wincmd L` I also do `| if winwidth(0) < 78 | wincmd T | ... ` to reopen it in a new tab if the help window becomes too narrow.

Comment: This is the only persistent and reliable solution on this page (`BufRead` event is not needed, `BufEnter` suffices).

Answer (score 7):

Put this in your `.vimrc`:

```
command -nargs=* -complete=help Help vertical belowright help <args>
```

Now you can open a vertical help with the `:Help` command (notice that the first-letter is uppercase)

Answer (score 7):

Put the following in your `~/.vim/ftplugin/help.vim`

```
wincmd L
```

Can't get simpler than this :)

Comment: This doesn't work anymore. See this issue on Github: https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/1806

Answer (score 4):

Here's an autocmd in lua for neovim.

```lua
-- Open help window in a vertical split to the right.
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd("BufWinEnter", {
    group = vim.api.nvim_create_augroup("help_window_right", {}),
    pattern = { "*.txt" },
    callback = function()
        if vim.o.filetype == 'help' then vim.cmd.wincmd("L") end
    end
})
```

Answer (score 3):

This moves the help window *once*. So you can freely move it around after the window is created.

```
if has('autocmd')
  function! ILikeHelpToTheRight()
    if !exists('w:help_is_moved') || w:help_is_moved != "right"
      wincmd L
      let w:help_is_moved = "right"
    endif
  endfunction

  augroup HelpPages
    autocmd FileType help nested call ILikeHelpToTheRight()
  augroup END
endif
```

The function, `ILikeHelpToTheRight()` will only run `wincmd L` once per window (it's what the `w:` prefix is for).

This is then called whenever a "help" file is opened.  This doesn't have the side-effects of EdJoJob's solution.

Answer (score 3):

Dynamically open help windows at the top if there's more than one window in current tab, or on the right, if there's only one window:

```
if winnr('$') > 2
    wincmd K
else
    wincmd L
endif
```

You'll need to place this in `ftplugin/help.vim` or use it with an `autocmd`, e.g.:

```
augroup my_filetype_settings
autocmd!
autocmd FileType help if winnr('$') > 2 | wincmd K | else | wincmd L | endif
augroup END
```

Answer (score 2):

*This is meant to add to @m42's answer, but I don't have 50 rep yet here on SO proper to add to the comments.*

Add `nnoremap <C-H> :vert bo help` to .vimrc

Now pressing Ctrl-H in Normal mode will jump into Command mode, prefixed to open help in a vertically split window to the right. 
Include a trailing space after `help·`<-- at the end of the config line for best results.

This mapping allows you to still use `:help` \ `:h` to open a horizontally split window or cycle through your previous help command history without the prompt auto-expanding.

Answer (score 1):

I settled on the following:

```
" Open help in a vertical split or a new tab. 
augroup my_help
    " Remove current group to avoid double runs
    autocmd! 
    " If a help buffer is opened then try to move it to the right. If now it
    " doesn't fit help text (78 chars) then move it to a new tab.
    autocmd BufEnter * if &filetype == 'help' | wincmd L | if winwidth(0) < 78 | wincmd T | endif | endif
augroup END
```

It works for me in both vim and neovim.
`FileType help` doesn't work in neovim if I reopen help because the help buffer remains hidden in neovim while vim seems to unload it.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use, taken from docwhat's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24795721/5952189). You can change values to your liking.

```
function! MoveWindowToRightOrNewTab()
    if winwidth(0) < 165
        wincmd T
    else
        wincmd L
        vert resize 85
    endif
endfunction

" Open help in a vertical split or a new tab.
augroup HelpWindowOnRight
    " Remove current group to avoid double runs
    autocmd!
    " If a help buffer is opened then try to move it to the right. If now it
    " doesn't fit help text (80 chars) then move it to a new tab.
    autocmd FileType help call MoveWindowToRightOrNewTab()
augroup END
```