# Open two help windows in vertical splits

Tags: vim

[Opening Vim help in a vertical split window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630884/opening-vim-help-in-a-vertical-split-window) explains how to open help in a vertical split. However, suppose I run `help fzf` followed by `vert help vim-go`. Vim ignores the `vert` and just replaces the `fzf` help with `vim-go` help.

How can I open two help subjects in side-by-side splits?

Answer (score 7):

You are right `:help` does not respect `:vert`. `:help` tries to have only 1 help window active per tab pane. However you can cheat this a bit by splitting the help window with `<c-w>v` / `<c-w>s` / `:split` / `:vsplit` then running your `:help` command.

```
:vs | help foo
```

Alternatively if you accidentally opened another help file and forgot to split before hand you can use `:sb #` combined optionally with `:vert`, e.g. `:vert sb #`.